# Ошибка при подключении файла

Tags: c++, файлы

Добрый день. Пытаюсь решить одну задачу, надо, чтобы читались данные из файла. Написал код. Выдает ошибку ***#include expects "FILENAME" or*** . Подскажите, что делать. Заранее спасибо

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

int main()
{
    int A, B, N, K = 1;

    ifstream file("input.txt");
    file.open;
    file >> A >> N;

    cin >> A;
    cin >> N;

    if ( ( 1 % gcd(A + 1, N) ) != 0){
        B = -1;
    }
    else{

        while ( (K*N + 1)%(A + 1) != 0 ){
            K = K + 1;
        }

        B = (K*N + 1)/(A + 1) - 1;
    }

    cout << B;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: убери точку с запятой после `<fstream>`

Comment: Уже. Не помогло(

Comment: file.open; - это не верно, это вообще-то говоря функция :)

Comment: А в какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка в третьей строке

Answer (score 1):

Уберите точку с запятой:

```
#include <fstream>;
```

Итерация 2. Теперь выбросьте строчку с `file.open`. Файл **уже** открыт в конструкторе.

Итерация 3. Выбросьте или чтение из файла, или из `cin`. Вы пытаетесь читать и оттуда, и отсюда...

Comment: Да, это я случайно. Сейчас исправлю. Однако ошибка все равно осталась.

Comment: Но изменилась :) См. дополненный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Простой и понятный пример работы с файлом:

```
// print the content of a text file.
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream ifs;

  ifs.open ("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);

  char c = ifs.get();

  while (ifs.good()) {
    std::cout << c;
    c = ifs.get();
  }

  ifs.close();

  return 0;
}
```